# gnuplot changed 5.2->5.4 does not mirror ytics to y2tics

Tags: gnuplot

I always (until v5.2) had the tics on y axis mirrored on y2 axis. Since the 5.4 update this does not happen. I did not find an option to enable this.

How do I request to mirror y tics on the y2 axis?

I am on fedora 36 which has "gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 3".

TIA

[later, asked to add a sample script]

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color "Helvetica" 22 size 19,10
set timefmt "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
set autoscale xy
set style data lp
set xdata time
set xtics 3600
set grid xtics
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fillcolor rgb"white" behind
set key right bottom    # legend location

set output "ups_w.ps"

set ylabel "UPS Load (W)"
set ytics 10
set yrange [0:100]
set grid ytics

plot    "ups_load"      using 1:2  title 'UPS load W'        w l lw 5
exit
```

The end (as an example) of `ups_load` is

```
20220709173701 30
20220709173801 28
20220709173901 26
20220709174001 28
20220709174101 28
20220709174201 26
20220709174301 27
20220709174401 28
20220709174501 28
20220709174601 28
20220709174701 28
20220709174801 28
20220709174901 28
```

Adding `set ytics mirror` had no effect.

AFAIK I made no change to the script yet the output changed after gnuscript v5.4 (as part of fedora 36 upgrade) was installed.

HTH

[even later] I now restored my script from earlier than the gnuplot update and there are no tic number showing on the y2 axis (using v5.4).

So, same old script that with 5.2 did mirror to y2, does not with 5.4.

FYI I have the old plots (emailed to me daily) and they changed on the day gnuplot was updated.

Comment: The relevant command is `set ytics mirror`.  This has always been the default and it remains so in version 5.4.   If you show your complete script, perhaps we can see what you have done to change it.

Comment: Script and sample data file added to original report.

Comment: You have two contradicting commands for the grid, but I don't see any obvious reason why `set ytics mirror` should have no effect. A blind guess: Is there some strange stuff in `.gnuplotrc`? If you don't know where it is try `show loadpath`.
You could also have a look at the output of `show ytics`.

Comment: I do not have `~/.gnuplotrc`. There is `/usr/share/gnuplot/5.4/gnuplotrc` which is all commented out. Also, I see only one `set ytics` command in my script. Removing `autoscale` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be using the word "mirror" to mean something different than what gnuplot uses it to mean.   The command `set ytics mirror` tells gnuplot to draw identical tic marks along both the left and the right edges of the plot's bounding rectangle.   It does not do anything at all to y2 axis tics or labels.  The vertical position of these tics is controlled by the y axis range and tic intervals.

I am guessing that what you are asking is how to enable the y2 axis tics and y2 tic labels, and draw tic marks and labels for both y and y2.  In this case you should disable mirroring for both y and y2 so that the y axis commands will affect only what is drawn on the left border and the y2 axis commands will affect only what is drawn on the right border.

```
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics nomirror
```

These commands by themselves leave y and y2 with independent range and scale, which is useful if you are superimposing plots from two data sets with unrelated y values, e.g.

```
plot 'temperature' axes x1y1, 'rainfall' axes x1y2
```

In this case the y axis might run from 10 to 50 in °C, while the y2 axis might run from 0 to 5 in centimeters.

If you want to force y and y2 to have identical range and scale, you can use the command

```
set link y2
```

The general form of the `set link` command handles cases where the y and y2 axes are related but not identical (e.g. °F on y1 and °C on y2).

```
set link y2 via (y-32)*5./9. inverse (y*9./5.)+32
```

**Amended answer here in response to revised question. **

Taking it from the top.

- Commands of the form `set noFOO` were deprecated in gnuplot 5 in favor of `unset FOO`.  Both versions 5.2 and 5.4 will accept this form but warn that it is deprecated. The actual command is `unset timestamp`. Version 5.2 accepted the incomplete form `unset time` but version 5.4 requires more letters to disambiguate `unset timestamp` from `unset timefmt`.
- The script you show says both `set ytics 2` and `set y2tics 2`.  But this cannot be the script used to generate the attached output because the attached output show tic intervals of 0.02 instead
- I replaced both those commands with `set ytics 0.02`
- I added the single command `set link y2`
- I generated some dummy data just for the purpose of generating a test plot (not time data so I turned off the x-axis time labels).
- Both versions 5.2 and 5.4 default to key placement at the top of plot.  The output you show has it at the bottom, so again that is an indication that the script shown is not the same as originally used. I added a command `set key bottom`.
- I then get the plot below from your script using version 5.4.3
  [image]

**Bottom line:**

The only changes needed to switch from version 5.2 to version 5.4 are

1. Replace `set notime` with `unset timestamp` or delete altogether
2. Add the command `set link y2`.  You could put this in your init file ~/.gnuplot and not have to modify working scripts any further.

Comment: See my response above, don't know why the forum shows my answer earlier.

Comment: Looks like it. I will try to add the `link` command to the init part (my script has one) but I think that I tried it and it interfered with the plots where y and y2 are different items (now tested again and it does obliterate the tick on y2). I now added the `link` command where it is appropriate.

Comment: @Eyal, please mark this answer or yours with the green tick to show they have a solution. I've just experienced the exact same problem after upgrading from raspbian 11 to 12 and indeed the `set link y2` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ethan.

Adding `set link y2` by itself did not add to the y2.

Adding

```
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics nomirror
set link y2
```

shows y2tics but at a default settings and I had to add more:

```
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics nomirror
set link y2
set y2tics 10
```

and now it works.

Actually using only this:

```
set link y2
set y2tics 10
```

did the trick too.

Is there a way to say "use all ytics settings for y2tics"? My "real" script has recipes for about 100 plots and now I will have to update most.

Now my question remains: What changed between 5.2 and 5.4 to require these additions? I did not find any settings/configs that changed.

As I explained, I recovered the script as it was before the software update.
I have a full system backup done just before the software upgrade.

Using the old script with 5.4 today has no y2tics showing.
My records show that this old script produced plots with tics using 5.2, then changed from the day following the software update to show none.

BTW `show loadpath` says:

```
        loadpath is empty
        gnuplotrc is read from /usr/share/gnuplot/5.4
        no XAPPLRESDIR found in the environment,
            falling back to "@X11_APPDEFAULTS_DIR@"
```

Comparing `/usr/share/gnuplot/5.2` to `.../5.4/` the only non-comment changes I see are in `gnuplot.gih` which looks like a help file and in:

```
  js/gnuplot_mouse.js
  js/gnuplot_svg.js
```

Anything else I should check?

Comment: As I recall, the problem was that in version 5.2 if you did not give an explicit range for y2 it tried to use the immediately previous settings for the y1 axis.  This kinda/sorta worked but only for simple cases.  Try for example `set y2tics; set yrange [1:100]; set log y; plot x*x`.  In version 5.2 this sequence of commands would happily place linear tics on y2 even though the plot uses a log scale y axis.  Version 5.4 would reject such a sequence of commands.  I think `set link y2` gets you back to the version 5.2 behavior for the simple linear-scale cases that worked correctly before.

Comment: My understanding: it is an intentional change which affects my simple plots. Now I have to adjust all my relevant (where data was plotted only on the y axis) plots. And sadly there is no option to just plot the y axis symbology on y2.

Comment: I tested gnuplot versions 4.6, 5.0, 5.2, 5.4 and current tip.   None of them produce y2 tics or labels using the sample script provided.  Can you take a step back and describe exactly what you want the output to look like?  Do you want a single set of tic labels on the right side of the plot rather than the left side?  Duplicate labels on both sides?  Something else?  Or maybe attach a copy of an old output you were happy with?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932922/5699510 for more details.

Comment: I have amended my original answer. Really the only thing you need is a script that actually works in 5.2 and the one new command `set link y2`.

Comment: I am satisfied that this discussion went as far as it can go, and consider my question answered. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am now using a different plot (`temp_all`) because the original I reported (`ups_w`) is not part of the daily emails.

This is the script as used during the period of these (see beblow) two images. It is generated by a much larger cgi-bin script, which includes this stanza:

```
        debdir='/data/logs/gnuscript'
        cat "$GNUPLOTSCRIPT"    >/data/logs/gnuscript/gnu-temp_all.script
        gnuplot <"$GNUPLOTSCRIPT"
```

You will notice that this one does include a reference to y2:

```
set y2tics 2
```

Also, v5.4 did not like

```
set notime
```

which I later commented out. I do not even remember why it is there...

```
gnu-temp_all.script
===================
set term postscript eps enhanced color "Helvetica" 22 size 19,10
set timefmt "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
set notime
set autoscale xy
set ytics 2
#set size 2,2
set style data lp
set xlabel "2022-07-11 10:40:32, src=temp\\_all?from=36h?x=1h, since=20220709220117"
set xdata time
set xtics 3600
set grid xtics
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fillcolor rgb"white" behind
set key right bottom    # legend location

set output "temp_all.ps"

# common temperature limit
otemp=0
ntemp(temp) = ((itemp=0+temp), (itemp >= 85 ? otemp : (otemp=itemp, itemp)))

# default value if zero
dval(v,d) = (0 == 0+v ? 0+d : 0+v)

set ylabel "Temperature (dC)"
set grid ytics
set y2tics 2
set key left top                # legend location
plot    "temp_bed_floor"   using 1:2 title 'bedroom floor (10:38:14 8.75)'   w l lw 5 lc rgb  "#40A040",        "temp_bed_bed"     using 1:2 title 'bedroom bed (8.625)'     w l lw 5 lc rgb "black",   "temp_bed_top"     using 1:2 title 'bedroom top (10.875)'     w l lw 5 lc rgb    "#80F080",     "temp_bed_heater"  using 1:2 title 'bedroom carpet (8.9375)'  w l lw 5 lc rgb "#C0FF60",        "temp_bed_door_in" using 1:2 title 'bedroom door (8.875)'    w l lw 5 lc rgb "#4040A0",         "temp_bed_door_out" using 1:2 title 'bedroom bathroom (11.5625)' w l lw 5 lc rgb "#8080C0",     "temp_bed_bme"     using 1:2 title 'bedroom bme (10.84)'     w l lw 5 lc rgb "brown",   "temp_wardrobe"    using 1:2 title 'wardrobe (10:37:13 8.5625)'        w l lw 5 lc rgb "gray",  "temp_north_roof"  using 1:2 title 'north roof (10:37:13 6.4375)'      w l lw 5 lc rgb   "#00E0F0",     "temp_panels"      using 1:2 title 'PV panels (10:37:13 18.5)'       w l lw 5 lc rgb       "orange",    "temp_living"      using 1:2 title 'living room (10:38:13 7.125)'     w l lw 5 lc rgb         "#FF7070",        "temp_raked"       using 1:2 title 'living ceiling (10:38:15 8)'  w l lw 5 lc rgb          "#E0A0A0",   "temp_dining"      using 1:2 title 'dining room (10:38:47 7.8125)'     w l lw 5 lc rgb         "magenta",       "temp_kitchen"     using 1:2 title 'kitchen (10:39:00 8.1875)'         w l lw 5 lc rgb        "#406080",        "temp_moist"       using 1:2 title 'moist esp-32c  )'   w l lw 5 lc rgb "#a0a0ff",      "temp_fridge"      using 1:2 title 'fridge (10:38:53 8.0625)'          w l lw 5 lc rgb         "#0080C0",       "temp_music"       using 1:2 title 'music room (10:38:38 9.1875)'      w l lw 5 lc rgb          "#00FFFF",      "temp_roof"        using 1:2 title 'south roof (10:38:07 7.625)'      w l lw 5 lc rgb     "#0000FF",    "temp_weather"     using 1:2 title 'weather (10:38:26 7.1)'         w l lw 5 lc rgb        "#C08080",   "temp_work_window" using 1:2 title 'workroom window (10:38:38 7.25)' w l lw 5 lc rgb    "dark-violet",  "temp_work_room"   using 1:2 title 'workroom desk (10:40:01 16.4)'   w l lw 5 lc rgb      "#4040FF",    "temp_work_roof"   using 1:2 title 'workroom roof (10:40:01 6.8)'   w l lw 5 lc rgb      "#8080E0",     "bom"              using 1:2 title 'BOM (09:30:00 4.7)'             w l lw 5 lc rgb                 "red"
exit
```

The following images are from the daily email on the day before the upgrade and then the following day, showing the difference. The plots are generated at 5pm so they nicely bracket the upgrade time.

plot from 2022/06/09 (before the upgrade)
[image: plot from 2022/06/09]

This is the relevant log of the upgrade:

```
2022-06-09T18:04:52+1000 DEBUG Upgraded: gnuplot-common-5.4.3-3.fc36.x86_64
2022-06-09T18:04:52+1000 DEBUG Upgraded: gnuplot-latex-5.4.3-3.fc36.noarch
2022-06-09T18:04:52+1000 DEBUG Upgraded: gnuplot-wx-5.4.3-3.fc36.x86_64
2022-06-09T18:04:52+1000 DEBUG Upgraded: gnustep-base-libs-1.28.0-5.fc36.x86_64
```

It is possible that the upgrade installed other settings/configs that I am not aware of, let me know what to look for.

plot from 2022/06/10 (after the upgrade)
[image: plot from 2022/06/10]